# Storing time zone offset in Oracle DB as separate field

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, timezone, timezone-offset

I am working on air flight Java app and need to store local time with time zone information in Oracle DB.

`DATE`/`TIMESTAMP` types have less problems then `WITH TIME ZONE` analogs.

If I store local date in `DATE` field what type should I assign for offset as separate field in Oracle DB and Java/Hibernate mapping? I hope that date arithmetic would be easy both in Java and Oracle native SQL queries.

I can imaging only `INT(6)` to store offsets as seconds. Native Oracle SQL queries can use arithmetic operations:

```
departure_date + departure_off/(24*60*60)
```

In Java:

```
departureDate.atOffset(ZoneOffset.ofTotalSeconds(departureOff))
```

**UPDATE** I have no information for TZ region, like 'US/Pacific', only numeric offset.

Comment: Why do you think DATE/TIMESTAMP types have less problems?

Comment: **@WernfriedDomscheit** take a look to https://tonyhasler.wordpress.com/2010/09/04/tonys-tirade-against-timestamp-with-time-zone/

Comment: I read this blog, it mainly lists some performance issues. Bear in mind if you have to run time zone related offset calculations in your queries then you may withdraw those performance gains you would have with `DATE`/`TIMESTAMP` types

Comment: How do you plan to handle daylight saving hours?

Comment: I don't need to handle daylight saving hours. Departure events happen at specific time and external system provide time/TZ information. I just need to preserve this information and make range selects.

Answer (score 3):

I would first recommend to use `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, resp. `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE`, I think this would be the easiest way.

Otherwise I would store time zone offset as according ISO-8601, i.e. as `VARCHAR(6)` value like `+05:00`

Then you can make a very simple conversion to `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` like

```
SELECT FROM_TZ(departure_date, departure_off)
FROM ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't. Convert all the times to a common time zone (i.e. UTC) and then, when the front-end wants to display it in their local time zone it can do the conversion back from UTC.

```
INSERT INTO your_table ( departure_date )
VALUES (
  FROM_TZ(
    CAST( :your_date AS TIMESTAMP ),
    TO_CHAR( TRUNC( :your_offset / 60 ), 'FMS00' )
      || ':' || TO_CHAR( MOD( :your_offset, 60 ), 'FM00' )
  ) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
);
```

Or you could use `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.

```
CREATE TABLE departures (
  departure_date   TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE
);

INSERT INTO your_table ( departure_date )
VALUES (
  FROM_TZ(
    CAST( :your_date AS TIMESTAMP ),
    TO_CHAR( TRUNC( :your_offset / 60 ), 'FMS00' )
      || ':' || TO_CHAR( MOD( :your_offset, 60 ), 'FM00' )
  )
);
```

However, if you really want to store date and offset separately then use `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND`:

```
CREATE TABLE departures (
  departure_date   DATE,
  departure_offset INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND
);

INSERT INTO departures VALUES (
  :your_date,
  NUMTODSINTERVAL( :your_offset, 'SECOND' )
);
```

Comment: *Convert all the times to a common time zone (i.e. UTC) and then, when the front-end wants to display it in their local time zone it can do the conversion back from UTC.* - That is actually how `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE` works. The only difference is: Instead of `UTC` it uses `DBTIMEZONE` (which could be set to `UTC` of course)